# compute only the last exponential weighted moving average pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I know that, for a pandas, by doing

```
test_df.ewm(halflife=half_life_for_mean).mean()
```

I could get the exponential moving average at all times...

Yet I am actually only interested in the last one and i suspect by calculating all of it it may be a bit inefficient. In other words, all I need is

```
test_df.ewm(halflife=half_life_for_mean).mean().iloc[-1]
```

Yet... I am wondering if this may be too inefficient it essentially needs to calculate from start to construct `ewm().mean()`.

Is there other method that allows me to get the last element only without spending time to calculate the whole time dependent `ewm.mean()`.

Comment: There is a part of the very first element that remain in the calculation for the very last element.  The correct answer is no.  The practical answer is that you can approximate it with a limited series.  `test_df.iloc[-10:].ewm(halflife=half_life_for_mean).mean().iloc[-1]`.  Depending on the halflife, you can ignore anything prior to a certain number of observations.  How many you take in, is upto how precise you need to be.

Comment: Following @piRSquared: you can basically decide on `k` halflife periods, that suit your precision for loosing starting values. But if you want a sort of rolling-window smoothing maybe some other method would suffice.

Comment: Here's the doc on rolling: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An other technique**

This time we use the `online` method :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 9],
                   })

online_ewm = df['col1'].ewm(alpha=0.5, adjust=False).online()
df['ewm'] = online_ewm.mean()


new_values = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[10, 11, 13]
                           })

def add_newRow(df, new_values, ncol, online_ewm):
    r = pd.concat([df, new_values], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    r.loc[len(df):len(r), 'ewm'] = online_ewm.mean(update=r.loc[len(df):len(r), ncol])
    return r

new_df = add_newRow(df, new_values, 'col1', online_ewm)

print(new_df)
```

```
    col1        ewm
0      1   1.000000
1      1   1.000000
2      2   1.500000
3      3   2.250000
4      3   2.625000
5      5   3.812500
6      8   5.906250
7      9   7.453125
8     10   8.726562
9     11   9.863281
10    13  11.431641
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's choose the recursive option in order to calculate weighted moving average starting from the latest calculated value.

According to [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) :

> When adjust=False, the exponentially weighted function is calculated
> recursively:

> `y0 = x0`

> `y(t) = (1-alpha) * y(t-1) + alpha * x(t)`

We create the following script based on that property :

**Proposed script**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 9],
                   })
# Parameters must be named
df['ewm'] = df['col1'].ewm(alpha=0.5, adjust=False).mean()


def add_newRow(df, src, dst, new_values, dlen, alpha):
    df = (
           pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({src:new_values,})], join='outer', ignore_index=True)
           ).fillna(np.nan)    
    # Fill null values
    for n in range(dlen, len(df)):
        df.at[n, dst] = (1-alpha) * df.iloc[n-1][dst] + alpha * df.iloc[n][src]
    # Return filled df
    return df

df = add_newRow(df, src='col1', dst= 'ewm',new_values=[10, 11, 13], dlen=len(df), alpha=0.5)

print(df)
```

**Result**

```
    col1        ewm
0      1   1.000000
1      1   1.000000
2      2   1.500000
3      3   2.250000
4      3   2.625000
5      5   3.812500
6      8   5.906250
7      9   7.453125
8     10   8.726562
9     11   9.863281
10    13  11.431641
```

**Checkings**

Let's consider we have the complete data list since the beginning and let's apply pandas `ewm` on it.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13],
                   })
# Parameters must be named
df['ewm'] = df['col1'].ewm(alpha=0.5, adjust=False).mean()

#     col1        ewm
# 0      1   1.000000
# 1      1   1.000000
# 2      2   1.500000
# 3      3   2.250000
# 4      3   2.625000
# 5      5   3.812500
# 6      8   5.906250
# 7      9   7.453125
# 8     10   8.726562
# 9     11   9.863281
# 10    13  11.431641
```

Everything is ok. Same datas.

Function `add_newRow` plays its role and adds new datas with ewm calculations limited to these new datas.